# Create a program that takes as input a string of digits and outputs the sum of the even and the sum of the odd digits

Tags: c++, string, input

> Create a program that takes as input a string of digits and outputs
>   the sum of the even and the sum of the odd digits.  This program is in
>   C++
>
> NOTE: It is recommended that you use a "for" loop to iterate over the
>   sting of digits. HINT: Use the modulus operator to determine even or
>   odd digits.
>
> A clever method of converting a "char" to an "int" is as follows link:
>
> ```
> char a = '4';
> int ia = a - '0';
> ```
>
> The above code takes advantage of the character's position in the
>   ASCII table to convert it to an integer.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
int main() {
  int sumOdd = 0;  // For accumulating odd numbers, init to 0
  int sumEven = 0; // For accumulating even numbers, init to 0
  int digits;      // Sum from 1 to this upperbound
  // Prompt user for an upperbound
  cout << "Please enter a string comprised ONLY of digits:" << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cin >> digits;

  // Use a while-loop to repeatedly add 1, 2, 3,..., to the upperbound
  int number = 1;
  while (number <= digits) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) { // Even number
      sumEven += number;   // Add number into sumEven
    } else {               // Odd number
      sumOdd += number;    // Add number into sumOdd
    }
    ++number; // increment number by 1
  }

  // Print the results
  cout << "The string of digits \"" << digits << "\""
       << " contained "
       << "characters." << endl;

  cout << "The sum of the even digits is: " << sumEven << endl;
  cout << "The sum of the odd digits is: " << sumOdd << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is my output compared to the output I need

Input:

```
1234567890
```

Output:

```
Please enter a string comprised ONLY of digits:

The string of digits "1234567890" contained characters.
The sum of the even digits is: -380436870
The sum of the odd digits is: -997720815
```

Expected output

```
Please enter a string comprised ONLY of digits:

The string of digits "1234567890" contained 10 characters.
The sum of the even digits is: 20
The sum of the odd digits is: 25
```

Overall I'm having trouble counting the input and getting the correct formula for my even and odd numbers. Any help is appreciated thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, you don't need to convert a character digit to a numeric digit to test for even or odd.

Comment: You should use `std::string` to enter a *string* of digits.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `while(number <= digits)` that's your problem... just take a look what digits variable really is

Comment: `char a = '4'; int ia = a - '0'; ` - This manner of coverting characters to digits is infact smart.

Comment: FYI, the `char` type can be `signed`, `unsigned` or `char` and depends on the tools to interpret.  So, the expression `a` - `0` in the OP's example may exhibit an `unsigned` vs. `signed` type conversion issue.  For example, if `char` is unsigned, the expression will evaluate to unsigned but the receiving type (on the left hand side of assignment) is signed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is full of misconceptions and logical errors. Solving all of this would probably fill a (beginners) C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to keep the number in text form:

```
std::string number_as_text;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> number_as_text;
```

This allows you to check each digit for even or odd:

```
const size_t length = number_as_text.length();
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
  char digit_character = number_as_text[i];
  if (isdigit(digit_character))
  {
    if (digit_character % 2 == 0)
    {
       // digit is even
    }
    else
    {
       // digit is odd
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't like `isdigit()`, you can replace with:

```
if ((digit_character >= '0') && (digit_character < '9'))
```

An important note is that there is a difference between the textual representation of digits and the internal, numeric, representation of digits.

**Edit 1: `%` on `char` type**
The `char` data type is an integer.  The remainder operator, `%`, works on integer types.  Thus you can use `%` on `char` types.

*Note: this operation assumes that the character mapping of `'0'` is an even integer and the other digits are successive in values.*

Comment: @Stargateur Because characters are integers. And as such, the remainder operator, '%', which applies to integers can be applied to characters as well.

Comment: I like to prefer `for(char digit : number_as_text){ isdigit... }` It looks a bit cleaner to me

Answer (score 1):

Read the inputs in a string field and not an integer as -

```
std::string digits;
```

Then, just run a valid loop to find out the sum of the even digits and the odd digits -

```
 for(int i=0; i<digits.length(); i++){
            int digit = digits[i]-'0';
            if(digit % 2 == 0)
                sumEven+=digit;
            else
                sumOdd+=digit;

        }
```

Below is a running piece of code.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int sumOdd = 0;  // For accumulating odd numbers, init to 0
  int sumEven = 0; // For accumulating even numbers, init to 0
  std::string digits;      // Sum from 1 to this upperbound
  // Prompt user for an upperbound
  cout << "Please enter a string comprised ONLY of digits:" << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cin >> digits;

  // Use a while-loop to repeatedly add 1, 2, 3,..., to the upperbound
  int number = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<digits.length(); i++){
        int digit = digits[i]-'0';
        if(digit % 2 == 0)
            sumEven+=digit;
        else
            sumOdd+=digit;

    }

  // Print the results
  cout << "The string of digits \"" << digits << "\""
       << " contained "
       << "characters." << endl;

  cout << "The sum of the even digits is: " << sumEven << endl;
  cout << "The sum of the odd digits is: " << sumOdd << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running your example without converting the digit from character with integer.  Apply the remainder operator directly to the character.

Comment: How would I add them up then? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong you are supposed to do sum of 1+3+5+7+9 and sum of 2+4+6+8+0. What are you doing instead is sum of all even numbers smaller than 1234567890 and sum of odd numbers smaller than 1234567890.
Maybe consider instead of getting all numbers in string by `cin >> digits` read it from input by characters one by one.
Check this code it reads characters from input and spits them back.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  cout << "Please enter a string comprised ONLY of digits:" << endl;
  cout << endl;

  char one;
  while ( true ) {
      cin >> one;
      // here will come your part with deciding even / odd and counting instead of pritnting out.
      cout << " " << one;
      if ( cin.peek() == '\n' ) { break; }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And now it's your turn to put it together.

Comment: I don't understand.  There is no checking of odd/even in your example.  Also, why are you limiting (hard coding) to 5?  See my answer.

Comment: This is obviously school assignment, so I am not going to blow it by posting solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline` to read all digits into a `std::string`:

```
std::cout << "Enter string of numbers: " << std::endl;
if (std::string numbers; std::getline(std::cin, numbers)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

<sub>Note the use of **conditional-if** above from the upcoming C++1z standard.</sub>

Then, you could make use of `std::pair` to neatly accumulate the odds and evens like this:

```
std::pair odd_even{0, 0};
for (auto c : numbers) {
    (c % 2 ? std::get<0>(odd_even) : std::get<1>(odd_even)) += c - '0';
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b93c7f56b2c8d1c)

Answer (score -1):

This one logically should work

```
for(int i=0; i<digits.lenght; i++){
        if(digits[i] % 2 == 0)
            sumEven+=digits[i];
        else
            sumOdd+=digits[i];

    }
```

Comment: You should attempt to compile code you submit as answers. As is, this example will not compile. Additionally, answers regarding non-functioning code are expected to contain an explanation of how the solution fixes the problem or of the mistake made in the original question.